# requests-cache url pattern expire after

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to implement caching for api requests. Therefore i want different `expire times` for different `endpoints`

Here is an example how it looks like:

```
from requests_cache import CachedSession

class API:
    def __init__(self):

        self.API_KEY = 'xxxx-xxxx'
        self.BASE_URL = 'https://xxx.xxx.com/1'
        self.HEADER = {
            'X-Api-Key': f'{self.API_KEY}',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

        # Session cache setup
        self.default_expire_after = 900
        self.urls_expire_after = {
            f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint1': 3600,
            f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint1/*/endpoint2': 1800,
            f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint2/*/endpoint3': 900
        }

        self.session = CachedSession('api_cache', 
                                     backend='sqlite', 
                                     expire_after=self.default_expire_after, 
                                     urls_expire_after=self.urls_expire_after)
        self.session.headers.update(self.HEADER)
```

The problem here is, if i send a request to `/endpoint1/*/endpoint2` the expire time is set from the `/endpoint1`

I already read the docs [here](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/filtering.html#url-filtering) but i couldn't get it to work for my example. It seems that pattern matching is not working with endpoints like this.

If the pattern matching is not working this way, then my next question would be, how do i properly implement a [custom filter](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/filtering.html#custom-cache-filtering)

**EDIT:**

I think i got it to work by "rotating" the `urls_expire_after` dict and changing the urls

```
self.urls_expire_after = {
     f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint2/': 900,
     f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint1/': 1800,
     f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint1': 3600
}
```

Can someone give me an explaination for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because **the first matching pattern will be used**. Like you already found out, you will want to put your 'catch-all' pattern for endpoint1 at the **end** of the list:

```py
urls_expire_after = {
    f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint1/*/endpoint2': 1800,
    f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint2/*/endpoint3': 900
    # Match anything else from endpoint1 that wasn't matched by a previous rule
    f'{self.BASE_URL}/endpoint1': 3600,  
}
```

There are more details on this behavior in the docs, under [Expiration With URL Patterns](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/expiration.html#url-patterns).